# ember-data: Included data not sideloading

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it obvious to anyone why my '`product`' data is not side-loading?  I am seeing separate API requests to /product for each cart-item.  My `cart-item` model is:

```
export default Model.extend({
    cart: belongsTo('cart'),
    product: belongsTo('product', { async: true }),
    skuid: attr('string'),
    quantity: attr('number'),
    personalization: attr(''),
    variantCodes: attr(''),
    variantData: attr(''),
    prices: attr('')
});
```

An example API payload is (I am using `RESTAdapter`):

```
{
    "cart-items": [
        {
            "cart": "0048f8cc-ef50-11e7-8337-76502ffc62f3",
            "id": "ROVE949352B",
            "personalization": [],
            "prices": {
                "price": 74.95,
                "totalPrice": 74.95
            },
            "product": 4464,
            "quantity": 1,
            "skuid": "ROVE949352B",
            "variantCodes": [],
            "variantData": []
        },
        {
            "cart": "0048f8cc-ef50-11e7-8337-76502ffc62f3",
            "id": "BLK4226",
            "personalization": [],
            "prices": {
                "origprice": 0,
                "price": 60,
                "totalPrice": 60
            },
            "product": 4502,
            "quantity": 1,
            "skuid": "BLK4226",
            "variantCodes": [],
            "variantData": []
        }
    ],
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 4464,
            "images": {
                "image": "tristan-irish-watch.jpg",
            },
            "name": "Watch - Gold Plated Watch",
            "prices": {
                "price": 74.95
            },
            "skuid": "ROVE949352B"
        },
        {
            "id": 4502,
            "images": {
                "image": "BLK4226.jpg",
            },
            "name": "Serving Bowl",
            "prices": {
                "origprice": 0,
                "price": 60
            }
            "skuid": "BLK4226"
        }
    ]
}
```

The relationship works fine, it's just resulting in separate requests.  I tried async: false but ember is complaining that the data is not there:

```
Assertion Failed: You looked up the 'product' relationship on a 'cart-item' with id ROVE949352B but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify that the relationship is async
```

I've also tried using "includes" in the route model hook like:

```
model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('cart-item', { include: 'products' });
}
```

Any help appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I am using RESTAdapter (not JSON:API) and I'm side-loading data successfully with other models. I can’t for the life of me figure out what’s different with this one. For example, this is a very similar one, `saveditem`:

```
export default Model.extend({
    user: belongsTo('user'),
    product: belongsTo('product', { async: true }),
    dateAdded: attr('number')
});
```

The payload from the API (which sideloads the products) looks like this:

```
{
    "saveditems": [
        {
            "dateAdded": 1514914371,
            "id": "f51bf2b8-efe2-11e7-8337-76502ffc62f3",
            "product": 4502,
            "user": "me"
        },
        {
            "dateAdded": 1514440889,
            "id": "8c3a7f96-eb94-11e7-8337-76502ffc62f3",
            "product": 1312,
            "user": "me"
        }
    ],
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 4502,
            "images": {
                "image": "BLK4226.jpg",
            },
            "name": "Serving Bowl",
            "prices": {
                "origprice": 0,
                "price": 60
            },
            "skuid": "BLK4226"
        },
        {
            "id": 1312,
            "images": {
                "image": "GC689.jpg",
            },
            "name": "Classic Cross",
            "prices": {
                "price": 29.95
            },
            "skuid": "JDSGC689GCB"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sideloading works great on that - no extra API calls.  Stumped.

Answer (score 0):

`async: true` means to lookup them up separately (literally it means get the data asynchronously) so that will give you separate requests.

So you want `async:false`

Eyeballing your packets, I'd expect the property on the cart-item to be called `product_id`, not `product`. That may fix it.

Failing that I'd start digging into the Ember inspector to look into what data Ember thinks it's loading.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  Yeah, I tried async: false but got an error saying the data was not in the payload.  I added an update with details about a very similar model that is sideloading `product` data just fine.  In regards to ember-inspector, can you tell me what I should be looking at specifically?  I see my `product` data getting loaded (data tab) but it's because my `cart-item` relationship IS resolving, it's just having to do separate API calls (rather than using the sideloaded data)

Comment: In your update you have async: true still - so if you are using that code verbatim it will still not be sideloading the data. As I said above use 'product_id' in the json, not product, and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks!  The update contains code from a separate (but similar) model where side-loading does work.  It works regardless of whether `async` is set to `true` or `false`, or is not there.  I can tell this because there are no separate API calls to resolve the `product` relationship.  In regards to the OP (`cart-items`) I tried `product_id` and `productId` but still same result (separate API calls()

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship is called `product`, but the in the include you're referencing `products`. Because you're specifying the name of a relationship, the plurality matters. (My Ruby on Rails backend will throw an error if I use the wrong relationship plurality - your experience could vary depending on your backend implementation.)

See if this fixes your issue:

```
model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('cart-item', { include: 'product' });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  tried `include: 'product'` but no dice.  Still getting the separate API calls.  Also tried leaving it plural and changing the name of the relationship to `products` but that obviously doesn't work.  I do find the enforcement of singular/plural in ember to be a bit confusing sometimes, but I do understand why its done.